# What is the correct way to add external library?

Tags: ros, rosdep, external-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

recently a have problems using external library in ros nodes. I'm using GNU Scientific Library (GSL) in my ros node. So I have to find a way how to add gsl to build and link this node.

First, I found gsl package in ros packages, copied the files, add to ros path, and add depend to the my node manifest, but problem arise see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/34016/failed-to-find-rosdep) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/34032/rosdep-packagename) questions.

However, if I understand it correct, which is not necessarily the case, the only important thing of gsl package is that it exports this line in the manifest:

```
<cpp cflags="-I/usr/include/gsl" lflags="-lgsl -lgslcblas"/>
```

I can place this include a libraries directly into CMakeList.txt and get rid of gsl package completely see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Linking_against_an_external_library), the question is if it this is a desired approach?

Finally, I decided to ask more general question as the title states: what is the correct way to include external library (for example gsl) in the ros package?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34199/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-external-library?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gsl shouldn't be wrapped in a ros package. Instead, your node should use a rosdep dependency on it and the CMake code as in Martin's answer.

Unfortunately, libgsl is not yet in Fuerte's rosdep system. Have a look [here](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) for information on how to contribute new rosdep rules.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on 2015-01-15**:
404 file not found

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-15**:
@Akali, Swearing is not appropriate in our forums. I've edited for comment to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this would be the best approach, but what I do to include gsl is to add the following to my CMakeList.txt:

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules( gsl REQUIRED gsl )

add_executable( my_exec src/my_source.cpp )
target_link_libraries( my_exec ${gsl_LIBRARIES} )
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-16**:
Yeah, it helps, however does not answer the question what is the correct approach, thanks anyway.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-17**:
This is the first step of the correct approach. The rest involves adding a rosdep to your manifest.xml, and then making sure the rosdep is defined, as explained by @Lorenz.